# channel closure on channel using SslHandler sometimes triggers IllegalReferenceCountException

Tags: ssl, netty

I'm using Netty 4.1.58 [Update: and I also tried Netty 4.1.60]

Closing a channel that includes the SslHandler in its pipeline using the following methodology:

```
    channel.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
```

Sometimes (about 10% of the time) triggers an IllegalReferenceCountException with the following stack:

io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
at io.netty.util.internal.ReferenceCountUpdater.toLiveRealRefCnt(ReferenceCountUpdater.java:74) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.internal.ReferenceCountUpdater.release(ReferenceCountUpdater.java:138) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:100) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release(ReferenceCountUtil.java:88) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.safeRelease(ReferenceCountUtil.java:113) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove0(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:306) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.failFlushed(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:660) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.closeOutboundBufferForShutdown(AbstractChannel.java:678) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.shutdownOutput(AbstractChannel.java:671) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.handleWriteError(AbstractChannel.java:963) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp] 
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:943) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.flush0(AbstractEpollChannel.java:520) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:905) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1372) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:742) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:728) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.forceFlush(SslHandler.java:2099) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapAndFlush(SslHandler.java:815) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:792) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:1953) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.closeOutboundAndChannel(SslHandler.java:1921) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.close(SslHandler.java:743) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeClose(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:622) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:606) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.close(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:472) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.close(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:957) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:232) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener$1.operationComplete(ChannelFutureListener.java:44) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener$1.operationComplete(ChannelFutureListener.java:41) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:552) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.addListener(DefaultPromise.java:184) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:95) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.addListener(DefaultChannelPromise.java:30) ~[baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.baffle.shield.sql.mssql.ProxySession$ChannelConfiguration.close(ProxySession.java:582) ~[main/:?]
at io.baffle.shield.sql.mssql.ProxySession.release(ProxySession.java:290) ~[main/:?]
at io.baffle.shield.sql.mssql.SslUtil.lambda$configureSsl$0(SslUtil.java:248) ~[main/:?]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$5.run(SslHandler.java:2079) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:170) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [baffle-client-local-shaded-INTERNAL.jar:tier0-mvp]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_252]

Comment: You most likely do release the the message more then once in your handler. Without seeing more code it is hard to say for sure tho

Comment: When things go awry, it's handling the Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER that was passed via the writeAndFlush, and it tends to be after it goes down the following path after the 'flush': io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.handleWriteError. Although the correlation is not 100%.

Comment: Well, that was tricky. In SslHandler.wrapAndFlush, the 'wrap' method invoked can produce a ByteBuf that it subsequently expects to release in 'forceFlush'. That ByteBuf was a TLS alert which I was forwarding. So the solution was to forward a copy of that TLS alert ByteBuf instead, so that 'forceFlush' would be happy.

Comment: Are you saying that netty miss to retain here or was it your own handler that was missing it ?

Comment: @SpenceJackson we are facing a similar issue. can you please explain what you did to solve this issue. Where are you forwarding the copy of that TLS alert.

Comment: In my situation, SSL isn't the last stage of the pipeline, so I need to forward the packet to the next stage. But it's possible that SSL could output a TLS alert, which SslHandler.wrapAndFlush expects to release. So I need to forward the TLS alert while also retaining it, so I make a packet copy and forward that instead. Hence, the following weird code:       int tlsRecordType = packet.getByte(0);
      if (tlsRecordType == 0x15) {
        out.add(packet.copy()); // Don't encapsulate TLS alert messages
      } else { /* my normal encapsulating/forwarding code */ }